# Mocking a controller enters controller instead of mock

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I am trying to get comfortable with tests in Laravel and playing around with Dusk.

Given I have the following controller:

```
class CoursesController extends Controller {

    private ApiServiceProvider $api;

    public function __construct(ApiServiceProvider $apiServiceProvider) {
        $this->api = $apiServiceProvider;
    }
    public function getCoursesCache(array $cIds = []) : array {
// Breakpoint here - always gets hit when running tests
        if (empty($cIds)) {
            $cIds = Request::capture()->query('cIds');
            $cIds = explode(',', $cIds);
        }

        return $this->api->getCoursesCache($cIds);
    }
}
```

Which is used by a route:

```
Route::get('/api/v1/courses/cache', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\CoursesController@getCoursesCache')->name('courses.cache');
```

This route is used internally by a VueJS component, which is ultimately what I'd like to test.

I am using Dusk to do some browser based testing and I want to mock the controller response for `getCoursesCache`.  However, when I use the following (with a breakpoint in the controller method) I always enter the controller instead of just returning the mock.

```
  $courseController = $this->mock(CoursesController::class)->makePartial();
  $item = new CourseCacheItem();
  $item->name = $course->name;
  $courseController->shouldReceive('getCoursesCache')
    ->with([$course->getKey()])
    ->andReturn([$item]);
  $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($course) {
    $browser->visit('/')
      ->waitFor('.course-card-container--data-loaded', 10)
      ->screenshot('filename')
      ->assertSee($course->name);
  });
```

I've also tried this to create the mock:

```
$cc = $this->createMock(CoursesController::class);
$item = new CourseCacheItem();
$item->name = $course->name;
$cc->expects($this->once())->method('getCoursesCache')->with([$course->getKey()])->willReturn([$item]);
```

Edit: I've also now tried Mocking and Spying on the injected service `ApiServiceProvider` but the code enters that real class during the test run as well.

My expectation is that my breakpoint within the actual CoursesController would never be hit - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If there is no breakpoint, will your code exec as expected as a Mockery?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: what should I expect as a Mockery? If I let the code continue to run it just returns empty because the real endpoint doesn't have the data.

Comment: That's seems not correct. I'm not full understanding mockery, but as I know, even if you didn't exec, it should always return a mockery class instead of null.

Comment: What's the result when you trying to dd `$courseController` after you `makePartial`?

Comment: @Charlie - so you're asking what the mock object looks like? I never said that returns null.

Comment: well then... what does " If I let the code continue to run it just returns empty" meaning...  just curious.

Comment: I'm guess that you ain't using mock instance and that's the problem, but I never used Dusk before so can't confirm.

Comment: you can use `instance` calling instead of Controller. Try `$this->instance(CoursesController::class, $courseController);`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that you are dealing with two separate Laravel Runtime.
You can check this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/152) for more infos.
Basically, when you are making a Dusk test with an Http call, Dusk will make a real Http call to a fresh Laravel instance/runtime (using Chrome Headless).
So you end up having one runtime where you are lunching the test, and the second one where dusk is making an http call.
The second Laravel instance is not running your Mock and doesnt know about it. That's why you end up in the actual Controller.
One solution i found in the past is making a route responsible to mock what i need.
This route should be called in the the html page before the assertion is happening.
So when you make a Dusk http call some Js (in the second Laravel instance) will call the route and the mock will be setup.
Fortunately for you there is great package that can handle this for you. https://github.com/NoelDeMartin/laravel-dusk-mocking

With that being said, i think here you don't need all this overhead for your testing case. Juste manipulate the cache and make the assertion.
Also mocking controller is not the way to do in Laravel i think this is why you are running in trouble here.
I have reformatted your code and did the testing with the Laravel provided methods:

```
//Controller.php
class CoursesController extends Controller
{
    private ApiServiceProvider $api;

    public function __construct(ApiServiceProvider $apiServiceProvider)
    {
        $this->api = $apiServiceProvider;
    }

    public function getCoursesCache(Request $request): array
    {
            if($request->has('cIds'))
            {
                $cIds =$request->input('cIds');
                $cIds = explode(',', $cIds);
            }else{
                //do smething with cIds empty so the var is not undefined
                $cIds=[];
            }


        return $this->api->getCoursesCache($cIds);
    }
}
```

In your Dusk testing file

```
//Lets assume that in your ApiServiceProvider you use the Cache facade to store/get your cache,  
//you can manipule the cache and assert the value after that  

Cache::put('course_name','some_course_name');

$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($course) {
    $browser->visit('/')
            ->waitFor('.course-card-container--data-loaded', 10)
            ->screenshot('filename')
            ->assertSee('some_course_name');
});
```

Comment: I understand the issue better now; however, I have not been able to get this to work using the referenced package.  I did open a support request in Github, and received a quick reply, but still no luck.  Do you have specific examples of using this?

Comment: The response has been updated

Comment: Unfortunately I can't just manipulate the cache - it's coming from a separate system so it's not as simple as mocking the `Cache` facade